# How can I render custom widget according to html tags using flutter_html package?

Tags: flutter, html-rendering

I have a HTML document and I want to render it with Flutter using flutter_html plugin. I want to render different typography differently. Eg. I want to have different font and size for bold and different for non-bold.

I tried reading the documentation which has a property for the Html constructor called `customRenderer`, I couldn't understand the implementation for it.

Below is the code from documentation.

```dart
  Html(
    data: """
      <!--For a much more extensive example, look at example/main.dart-->
      <div>
        <h1>Demo Page</h1>
        <p>This is a fantastic nonexistent product that you should buy!</p>
        <h2>Pricing</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet.</p>
        <h2>The Team</h2>
        <p>There isn't <i>really</i> a team...</p>
        <h2>Installation</h2>
        <p>You <u>cannot</u> install a nonexistent product!</p>
        <!--You can pretty much put any html in here!-->
      </div>
    """,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
    defaultTextStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'serif'),
    linkStyle: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.redAccent,
    ),
    onLinkTap: (url) {
    },
    customRender: (node, children) {
      if(node is dom.Element) {
        switch(node.localName) {
          case "video": return Chewie(...);
          case "custom_tag": return CustomWidget(...);
        }
      }
    },
  )
```

If I just can change font size and font family according to the tag name, it will do.

Comment: Did you find any solution?.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample using `flutter_html`. (as of typing this you should go with `flutter_html_all`. Same package but there has been some renaming. `customRender` is now `customRenders` (plural))

```
return Html(
    data: <span>Some normal HTML</span> then appears a <customtag>Some data in this one</customtag>,
    tagsList: Html.tags..addAll(['customtag']),
    customRenders:
    {
        customTagMatcher(): CustomRender.widget(widget: (context, buildChildren)
        {
            final element = context.tree.element!;

            // Your conditions with the element.
            // finally return your own custom widget:
            return Container(child: Text('My custom widget...'));
        }),
    }
);

CustomRenderMatcher customTagMatcher() => (context) => context.tree.element?.localName == 'customtag';
```

More info:
https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html#customrenders
https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/discussions/973

Answer (score 0):

On mobile you can use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/) to display html script on a page.

```dart
WebView(
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
    final String contentBase64 = base64Encode(const Utf8Encoder().convert(Source.html));
    webViewController.loadUrl('data:text/html;base64,$contentBase64');
  },
),
```

If you're planning to use this on web, you can use `dart:html`

```dart
void main() {
  // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'html-view-tag',
      (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
        ..srcdoc = Source.html
        ..style.border = 'none');

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

and on your Screen, add `HtmlElementView` like a Widget

```dart
body: Center(
  child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'html-view-tag')
),
```

I just defined the source html like this

```dart
class Source {
  static const html =
      '<!--For a much more extensive example, look at example/main.dart-->'
      '<div>'
      '<h1>Demo Page</h1>'
      '<p>This is a fantastic nonexistent product that you should buy!</p>'
      '<h2>Pricing</h2>'
      '<p>Lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b> sit amet.</p>'
      '<h2>The Team</h2>'
      '<p>There isn\'t <i>really</i> a team...</p>'
      '<h2>Installation</h2>'
      '<p>You <u>cannot</u> install a nonexistent product!</p>'
      '<!--You can pretty much put any html in here!-->'
      '</div>';
}
```